# Google Colab stops training at random iterations

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, yolo

I am training custom dataset on yolov4 on Google Colab but the training keeps stopping at random iterations. I get the ^C error which I am guessing means keyboard interrupt, however I am not interrupting the command at all. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you disconnected from Colab? I can see "16 hours left". Notice that with free version of Colab you can't use it for more that 12 hours. And even with the PRO version, the limit is 24 hours.

Comment: @SilentCloud no that isn't the issue. I got this after executing for only 30 mins. Runtime isn't disconnected also. But due to this I have to re-run the command.

Comment: I guess then you should post the code, unless it will be difficult to help you